# Accessing to Weights and Layers in Tensorflow Hub

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-hub

When I try to get the model from tensorflow-hub resporitory.
I can see it as a Saved Model format, but I cant get access to model architecture as well as weights store for each layer.

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/centernet/hourglass_512x512/1")
)
```

Is there any formal way to work with it?

All the attribute I can get through `model.__dict__` is not clear for a specific layer in the original model.

```
{'_self_setattr_tracking': True,
 '_self_unconditional_checkpoint_dependencies': [TrackableReference(name='_model', ref=<tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x7fe4e4914710>),
  TrackableReference(name='signatures', ref=_SignatureMap({'serving_default': <ConcreteFunction signature_wrapper(input_tensor) at 0x7FE4E601F210>})),
  TrackableReference(name='_self_saveable_object_factories', ref=DictWrapper({}))],
 '_self_unconditional_dependency_names': {'_model': <tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject at 0x7fe4e4914710>,
  'signatures': _SignatureMap({'serving_default': <ConcreteFunction signature_wrapper(input_tensor) at 0x7FE4E601F210>}),
  '_self_saveable_object_factories': {}},
 '_self_unconditional_deferred_dependencies': {},
 '_self_update_uid': 176794,
 '_self_name_based_restores': set(),
 '_self_saveable_object_factories': {},
 '_model': <tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject at 0x7fe4e4914710>,
 'signatures': _SignatureMap({'serving_default': <ConcreteFunction signature_wrapper(input_tensor) at 0x7FE4E601F210>}),
 '__call__': <tensorflow.python.saved_model.function_deserialization.RestoredFunction at 0x7fe315a28950>,
 'graph_debug_info': ,
 'tensorflow_version': '2.4.0',
 'tensorflow_git_version': 'unknown'}
```

I have also tried with `model.signatures['serving_default'].__dict__`, the Tensor represents for each layer is not visible

```
  [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, numpy=<unprintable>>],
```

Comment: Can you share which model in particular are you using so that we can reproduce the setup?

Comment: I simply load from model hub this model: model = tf.saved_model.load('/tmp/tfhub_modules/3085eb2fbe2ad0b69801d50844c97b7a7a5ecade')

Comment: In order to do that, you must have downloaded a model to `/tmp/tfhub_modules/` beforehand (trained models don't pop up in temporary folders of your system). How did you come up with that particular path?

Comment: yes. I get it through traditional hub.load()  from tensorflow_hub

Comment: I have update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the CLI tool `saved_model_cli` provided by the package [tensorflow-serving-api](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-serving-api/) it's possible to inspect a saved model. In the first step I downloaded and cached the model:

```py
from os import environ
import tensorflow_hub as hub

environ['TFHUB_CACHE_DIR'] = '/Users/you/.cache/tfhub_modules'
hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/centernet/hourglass_512x512/1")
```

Then I inspected the signatures and layers:

```sh
saved_model_cli show --dir /Users/you/.cache/tfhub_modules/3085eb2fbe2ad0b69801d50844c97b7a7a5ecade --all
```

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['input_tensor'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_UINT8
        shape: (1, -1, -1, 3)
        name: serving_default_input_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 100, 4)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
    outputs['detection_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 100)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:1
    outputs['detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 100)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:2
    outputs['num_detections'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:3
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

After that I used the debugger to understand how a saved model works internally and found the member fields `variables` and `trainable_variables` in `model.signatures['serving_default']` which stores the data (weights, ...) of the model. Here you see the output of `model.signatures['serving_default'].variables`:

[image: Inspection with the debugger]

Comment: you are correct, I forgot about the `.variables` part. Cheers man

Comment: it may be outside of the scope, but how can I get the input and output for each layer from the variable? how can I know which variable is connect to which ones?

Comment: You could give [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) a try, because the architecture of a graph and network can be very complex.

Comment: yes, but I want to access the model architecture like model.layers in keras, so that I can dynamically checking node.

Answer (score 0):

Short summary for the answer. We can access to the variables of a layer by `model.signatures['serving_default'].variables`